# Why is my loop iteration not yielding any results?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am attempting to query firebase realtime database to get all of the team ids a player has liked, and they can like a team more than once. So I have stored the teams in a set. I then would like to take this set and query firebase to get the team details from the teams node in my DB. I then want to populate a tableview with the teams details in the cells. The issue I am having is for some reason when I loop through the collection of team ids my table is not populating and my array is empty. But if I place a print statement within the closure it shows I am retrieving something. I attempted to have the getTeamIds function return a set upon completion and then in that closure iterate through the set and query the DB but that did not work. So then I decided to save the ids in the UserDefaults and while they store successfully the iterating through and query does not yield the results I am looking for. Any have any pointers I have been researching this for 2 days and have not found any similar situations.

```
  // this function should get the teamIds based on the users id 
 func getTeamIds(completion:@escaping (Set<String>)-> Void){
    let exhiRef = Database.database().reference().child("Fans").queryOrdered(byChild: "userId").queryEqual(toValue: self.userId!)
    var tempTeamIdSet = Set<String>()
    exhiRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        for child in snapshot.children{
             if let childSnapshot = child as? DataSnapshot,
            let dict = childSnapshot.value as? [String:Any],
                let teamId = dict["TeamId"] as? String{
                tempTeamIdSet.insert(teamId)
            }
        }
       let completedSet = tempTeamIdSet
        completion(completedSet)
        
    })
}
// this call is made in viewDidLoad() 
getTeamIds(){ set in
        self.teamIdsSet = set
        let teamIdsArray = Array(set)
        for teamId in teamIdsArray{
        
          getTeams(teamId: teamId)
       }

    }

func getTeams(teamId: String){
    print("HELPING")
    let exhiRef = Database.database().reference().child("Team").child(teamId)
        var tempTeams = [Team]()
        exhiRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
            for child in snapshot.children {
                if let childSnapshot = child as? DataSnapshot,
                    let dict = childSnapshot.value as? [String:Any],
                    let teamName = dict["teamName"] as? String,
                    let teamCoach = dict["teamCoach"] as? String{
                    let team = Team(id: childSnapshot.key, teamName: teamName, teamCoach: teamCoach)
                       
                    tempTeams.append(team)
                
             
                }
        
            }
            self.teamsRetrieved.append(team)
            self.table.reloadData() //table is empty
        })
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Start here and keep reading: http://www.programmingios.net/what-asynchronous-means/

Comment: This isn't an answer but there are a couple of issues with the code. 1) within the loop `for child in snapshot.children` you're defining a var team `let team = Team(id` and then appending it to an array `tempTeams.append(team)` but then you never do anything what that array. 2) You have two vars with the same name `let team` and `self.team` and that's confusing 3) this `self.team.append(team)` will only ever append one team - the last one from within the loop.

Comment: @Jay Thanks for the feedback I renamed my teams array which populates the table. I am appending the teams objects as they are created, in the for loop so why would there only be one team?

Comment: Not sure if you fully updated the code on the question but the issue still exists. You're iterating over the children in the snapshot and appending each one to an array `tempTeams` but then not doing anything with that array. The reason there's only one item in `self.teamsRetrieved` is because the last iteration through the loop assigns a Team to `let team = ` and then the loop ends, so `self.teamsRetrieved.append(team)` only gets that last team. It's also odd the function is called `getTeams` (plural) but you only pass in one teamId (singular)

Comment: Its called get teams because I am iterating through the teamsIdArray and passing each id to get the details. If I remove the function from the loop and remove the ".child(teamId) from my query I am able to successfully get every team from the DB.

Comment: But getTeams only gets one teams details, right? So if I am understanding, a better name would be called `func getTeamDetails(forTeamId: String`. Also, if you're getting the team details for one team, what exactly are you iterating over with the for loop `for child in snapshot.children`? I posted an answer which should help but if you can clarify a bit further and also include a snippet of your structure in your question (as text please)we would better understand what's being iterated over in the firebase function. Once I have more data, I can update my answer to better address the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your closure block runs in the background queue, and you are reloading table in the main queue using an array that has not been filled with data yet.

Solution: You need to wait for the closure to run its course and then reload. Move the reload code into the closure.

Comment: hmm. The OP is *attempting* to populate the array within the Firebase closure so I am not sure what this answer means *Move the reload code into the closure* as it already is. There are bunch of other issues (see my comment) but that's not one of them.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is two fold:

1. Each time the function is called a fresh array tempTeams is created and populated and then thrown out when the function goes out of scope
2. The last iteration through the loop a team var is created and that's the only item added to the teamsRetrieved array.

Here's your code with comments

```
func getTeams(teamId: String){
    let exhiRef = Database.database().reference().child("Team").child(teamId)
    var tempTeams = [Team]() //create a local empty array each time getTeams is called
    exhiRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        for child in snapshot.children {
            if let childSnapshot = child as? DataSnapshot,
            ...
                let team = Team(id: // create and populate a team var each time through
                                    //   the loop
                tempTeams.append(team) //append the team var to the tempTeams 
                                       //  local array from above
            }
        }
        //note 1: the local tempTeams array is now populated but now nothing is 
        //          being done with it - no code below this point does anything with it
        //
        //note 2: the for loop has concluded and the last 'let team =' that was populated
        //          in the loop is valid here
        //
        self.teamsRetrieved.append(team) //assign that last team that was created
                                         //  in the loop to the self.teamsRetrieved array
        self.table.reloadData()
    })
}
```

There's another issue as well to be aware of. It's great you're protecting your code by ensuring the fields read from Firebase exist. However, the way you've done it, it's all or nothing.

```
if let childSnapshot = child as? DataSnapshot,
   let dict = childSnapshot.value as? [String:Any],
   let teamName = dict["teamName"] as? String,
   let teamCoach = dict["teamCoach"] as? String{
   let team = Team(id:
```

What the above says is that if any of those fields are not found, no team is created and it fails silently and you'll never know what happened.

It's way better to handle the fields individually so if there is an issue, you can find it.

Try this

```
let allChildren = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
for dataSnap in allChildren {
   let name = dataSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "teamName").value as? String ?? "No name"
   ...
   let team = Team(
}
```

Keeping in mind it's not clear what we're actually iterating over since we are just getting one teams details. Will update once we know more.